# wordpress is_front_page() issue

Tags: post-meta, actions, frontpage

I am updating the page title of all pages with a function i have created:

```
function wpss_show_custom_description() {
    $wpss_disable = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'wpss_disable', true);
    $wpss_description = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'wpss_description', true);
    $wpss_description_auto = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'wpss_description_auto', true);
    if(wpss_check_post_type(get_post_type()) == 1 && $wpss_disable != 1){
        if($wpss_description){
            echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$wpss_description.'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$wpss_description_auto.'" />';
        }
    }

    if(is_front_page()){
        echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$home_title.'" />';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head','wpss_show_custom_description');
```

Every other page works, apart from the frontpage. Is i edit the header directly and do this it works:

```
if(is_front_page()){
    echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$home_title.'" />';
}
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Might be worth trying `is_home()` instead

Comment: i have also tried is_home(), that didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the minefield of the way home and front_page work in relation to "normal" home and "static" home pages.

In many situations `is_home` and `is_frontpage` both eval as true on the REAL homepage and also on the main blog page. The Codex says...

> This Conditional Tag checks if the main page is a posts or a Page.
>   This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.
>   It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the
>   Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to "Your latest posts",
>   or when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the
>   current Page being displayed.

I recommend bypassing the minefield by using this instead. Job done!

```
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ) { }
```

Comment: @danyo Did this help you out in the end?